# C++: Method overloading when inheritance and "using" are involved

Tags: c++

Say there are two classes: Base and Derived. The code is listed below. **My question** is, how does the program know `d.print()` (tagged with `A` in code) is meant to call `Derived::print()` instead of `Base::print()`?

Please note that I deliberately added `using Base::print;` to confuse the compiler. These two `print()` methods have the same signature (am I right?) and are not hiding each other because of the `using` statement.

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

class Base {
public:
    void print() { cout << "print() of Base is called\n"; }
};

class Derived : public Base {
public:
    void print() { cout << "print() of Derived is called\n"; }
    using Base::print; // I delibarately added this line
};

int main() {
    Derived d;
    d.print(); // A

    Base *pBase = (Base *)&d;
    pBase->print(); // B
}
```

The result is

```
 print() of Derived is called
 print() of Base is called
```

*Edit*: the accepted answer gave a quote. For readers' convenience I paste the (nearly) whole quoted paragraph here, split in sentence:

> Using-declaration introduces a member of a base class into the derived class definition, such as to expose a protected member of base as public member of derived.. (that's what I expected)
>
> If the name is the name of an overloaded member function of the base class, all base class member functions with that name are introduced. (that's what I expected, too)
>
> If the derived class already has a member with the same name, parameter list, and qualifications, the derived class member hides or overrides (doesn't conflict with) the member that is introduced from the base class. (solved my problem)

Comment: Well, maybe it isn't overloading..? But it is not the point of this question. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Is it really surprising to you? `using Base::print;` intorduces **all the overloads** (there could be more than one). It would be very distressing if it caused a conflict in your own class because of it.

Comment: @StoryTeller It was confusing me because I thought the `using` declaration should override the name hiding mechanism (like, "override the override"), so the compiler should be confused. But apparently this override is overridden again - so `Derived::print()` overrides `Base::print()` after all.

Comment: Here's the thing. There's no overriding going on at all. It's "overloading". And the using declaration is a must sometimes. I suggest you play with [this code for a bit](http://ideone.com/29aIqM). It's your own but slightly modified. Try adding the using declaration back in.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The explicitly introduced `using` does not hide the method you have in the derived class because of this rule (from the [cppreference documentation for `using`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/using_declaration))

> If the derived class already has a member with the same name, parameter list, and qualifications, the derived class member hides or overrides (doesn't conflict with) the member that is introduced from the base class.

The compiler is not confused, it's doing the right thing.  The `using` is not hiding the `print()` method in the derived class because it defines a `print()` method.

When you call `print()` with a `Base` pointer, `print()` is not virtual the base pointer can only call the method that is registered with the static type of the thing it is pointing to, i.e. `Base::print()`

Comment: Thanks for pointing out this webpage! I totally missed this one.

Comment: @user8385554 I answered `A` first followed by `B`, which part is confusing you?